# Is it correct and natural to say "allow someone a lot" meaning to allow someone to do a lot of things?

Tags: grammar, collocations

Is it correct and natural to say *allow someone a lot* meaning to allow someone to do a lot of things? For example:

> Parents **allow** their children **a lot** these days.

If it's not really natural and correct, what would a native English speaker say?

Comment: A lot of (or a great deal of) leeway is probably what you're looking for. https://ludwig.guru/s/a+lot+of+leeway

Comment: @RonaldSole For some reason "allow...a lot of leeway"  sounds very ackward to me, whereas "allowed a lot of leeway" sounds fine.

Comment: @DKNguyen I suggest that at least half a dozen verbs serve the purpose - **allowed, given, permitted, granted, accorded, afforded** and so on!

Comment: @RonaldSole I mean "allow" specifically sounds ackward with "leeway". I don't know why but it does. Whereas "allowed" sound fine.

Comment: On its own, I would assume that mean the children got given a lot of things, not permission to do a lot of actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not correct because the sentence does not specify the verb being allowed. It makes the sentence feel like it hasn't ended and leaves you hanging.

The closest form to your sentence would be "parents allow their children to do anything nowadays".
A native speaker probably wouldn't use the word "allow" at all when trying to make a sentence conveying that meaning.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So what would a native English speaker say to convey that meaning?

Comment: Ronald Sole's "Parents give/afford/grant their children a lot leeway/freedom these days" is pretty good. It's about as neutral as anything else I can think of. It also depends on what your intention is. Are you trying to say parents aren't as strict? Or that they aren't strict enough? Or that parents can't control their children?